# sp_OACreate error on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and trying to run "sp_OACreate" but fall over with the following message:

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HTTP_REQUEST, Line 26
sp_OACreate on MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0 failed

That occurs because I am setting a variable to get the return value of sp_OACreate and raise the above error if the return value is not 0. Now, the return value I get is "-6" but i don't know why it is happening? Any help on this would be good to help make this work.

Comment: Can you post some more code please?

Comment: DECLARE
@xhr INT
,@result INT
,@httpStatus INT
,@msg VARCHAR(255)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HTTP_REQUEST]
( 
@URI varchar(200), 
@response varchar(8000) OUT
)
AS

DECLARE
@xhr INT
,@result INT
,@httpStatus INT
,@msg VARCHAR(255)

EXEC @result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0', @xhr OUT

IF @result <> 0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OACreate on MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0 failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END
print 'attempting to open ' + @URI
EXEC @result = sp_OAMethod @xhr, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URI, false
IF @result <>0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod Open failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END

Comment: EXEC @result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0', @xhr OUT

IF @result <> 0 BEGIN RAISERROR('sp_OACreate on MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0 failed', 16,1) RETURN 
END

Answer (score 0):

Has the DBA disabled the use of stuff like this?  Can you execute other sp_OACreate code without issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts:

Is this enabled?

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures',1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

Can you use SQL CLR? Even at the best of times, sp_OA% was not recommended. SQL CLR allows things to be done more efficiently and easily.

Are you trying to use CLR via sp_OA%? [It's not allowed, KB 32284](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322884/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

Found what was going wrong. Basically was using the wrong version of 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP'. Was calling sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0' when'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0' or above were the right ones to use.